# What tag to use for Windows Shell questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I faced a situation where a user made a minor edit to my [Windows Shell method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659477/does-windows-shell-copyhere-method-support-symlinks) related question by removing *shell* tag from it.

We can't deny however Windows has shell as well, and one of the most popular and broadly used programs ever *Windows Explorer* represents GUI for that shell.

This leads to the suggestion to add a tag for Windows shell like *shell-method*, or *windows-shell*, or *shell32*, or similar. And the question, why such tag doesn't exists thus far, and if there is an equivalent synonym for Windows shell in SO tags collection?

Comment: _Shell_ is annoyingly overloaded in the Windows world: those extra items programs like to install on your right-click menus are _shell extensions_, for example.  That's quite different from the usage of _shell_ as a command-line/scripting interface.  Take that into account if you want a new tag.

Comment: Please read more about [Windows Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521731(v=vs.85).aspx) here. Possibly _windows-shell_ tag will suffice? I can understand some antagonism to Windows world from certain Linux devs, but hey guys lets face the reality bits. Windows does exist, and is the most used OS on the planet. For objectivity sake, we can't ignore it, and neither its shell. :)

Comment: @sambul35: That document makes it very clear why that *isn't* a "shell" in the same sense as the various Unix shells. The "Windows Shell" is really a registry of various objects, using an API, which can be accessed and manipulated in various ways. That's *not* how the term is used elsewhere. And since that term predates Windows itself, the tag "shell" shall refer to the common usage, not that specific Windows technology.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I ask you for an alternative to the tag when referencing Windows Shell in generic manner regardless in what construct it was used at the moment. Whatever your interpretation of Windows shell definition is, it doesn't mean we should not have relevant tag in the SO tags collection.

Comment: Yes, you are programming the [windows] [shell], using the [shell32] automation object.  The tag was removed by a Linux programmer, haters will hate.

Comment: May be _shell32_ is the appropriate tag?

Comment: FYI: Windows is *not* the most used OS by a long-shot. Android installs alone outnumber Windows installs. The only place Windows has majority install shares is desktop installs.

Comment: @HansPassant: "*The tag was removed by a Linux programmer, haters will hate.*" The [tag:shell] tag wiki clearly states it is for Unix-style shells. Not Windows cmd, not Powershell, and certainly not this thing which isn't at all like a Unix-style shell. This isn't about haters; this is about proper categorization.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara How about laptops? Anyway, Android proliferation in smartphones is not the reason to deny Windows Shell its own tag. :)

Comment: It says "most often associated", that does not mean *we own it, get off our lawn!*

Comment: I don't know about laptop vs desktop specifically, my usage of "desktop" includes both. I don't disagree about the tag, just the above statement about usage shares. :)

Comment: @Hans Passant In fact, "_most often associated_" is rather true for _bash_ when it comes to Linux.

Comment: Well, I recommend you do not use the [bash] tag.  Sigh.

Comment: I did further research and found that [windows-shell](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-shell/info) tag already exists, hence it may be used to tag Windows Shell related questions. As well, _shell32_ tag exists, though both are far less intuitive to find compare to _shell_.

Answer (score 4):

Windows actually has several shells. There's the general command line "shell", which has the tag [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd). There's Powershell, which appropriately has the tag [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell). Win10 will even be getting a legit bash shell of some form, which would presumably use the existing [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash).

Comment: However, only one Windows shell is officially named [Windows Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521731(v=vs.85).aspx). Your reasoning doesn't justify lack of the relevant tag. And neither using 2nd account to place serial downvotes and upvote your own comment in the referenced question, despite you already removed _shell_ tag from it, and thus there was no reason for the downvote.

Comment: "*Your reasoning doesn't justify lack of the relevant tag.*" I never said that there shouldn't be a relevant tag for that topic.

Comment: @sambul35: "*And neither using 2nd account to place serial downvotes and upvote your own comment in the referenced question, despite you already removed shell tag from it, and thus there was no reason for the downvote.*" Please take your paranoia out of this thread. I have no alt-accounts. I haven't edited your question or commented on it in any way. I have far more important things to do than to troll someone on Stack Overflow. ***People are not out to get you.***

Comment: I apologize, it was Dummy00001. :)

Comment: Would you consider adding to your answer, what tag do you propose for Windows Shell? I wanted to upvote or accept it, but don't know what exactly you propose?

Answer (score 2):

Either use one/some of these:

- [cscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cscript)
- [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript)
- [shell32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell32) This is the automation object, not a shell as the *nix world tend to look at it
- [wsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsh) which has [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wsh/synonyms)
- [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) if your question is about the starting and environment of the script.

I have never heard of *shell-method* in the context of WSH/CScript so in any case that would be a very bad name for a tag.

Comment: The question in question looks more like a batch script.

Comment: @rene The linked question refers to [CopyHere](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows Shell method. In that post the method is called from VBS, but in many other instances various Windows Shell methods can be called from Jscript, Javascript, Powershell, etc. More about [Windows Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521731(v=vs.85).aspx) here. Possibly _windows-shell_ tag will suffice?

Comment: @Braiam it does some hackery to start as a batch then to become a cscript

Comment: @Braiam  Its a typical hybrid batch script. :)

Comment: ah, that's why right in the middle I felt like reading klingon...

Comment: @Braiam There is MORE to hybrids, a lot more, with a combination of VBS, Jscript, Powershell, Javascript used in the same batch without saving stuff to files very efficiently and fast. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just taken a look at the current tags Stack Overflow offers.

I believe this is a great opportunity for us to ask a person (with good reputation) to make a new tag, which could be called something life windows-shell, or as you said: shell-method.

If ever you think you need to make a new tag (and if you don't have enough reputation to do so), 
then you can just add a temporary comment to your question: 
Can someone please create a tag (Name of Tag).

Comment: Exactly right IMO.

Comment: No, we already have [tag:wsh] which covers the topic already, among two other tags. No need to create a new tag.