# Synonymize [cscript], [wscript] -> [wsh]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Both [cscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cscript) and [wscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wscript) programs are implementations of Windows Scripting Host ([wsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsh)). So, all these three are basically about the same thing - at least either of the first two implies the 3rd. The only difference is `cscript` can use console operations.

Related: [What tag to use for Windows Shell questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330186/what-tag-to-use-for-windows-shell-questions/330191#330191)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, all three are about the same thing and do not deserve distinct tags. As such, the following merges have been done and corresponding synonyms created:

- [wsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsh) ← [wscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wscript)
- [wsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsh) ← [cscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cscript)
- [wsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsh) ← [wsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsf)

I also updated the tag wiki for the master [wsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsh) tag.

I was very tempted to make the master tag [windows-script-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-script-host) because it's far more descriptive than a TLA, but I restrained myself from going that far.

Comment: Why the [meta-tag:support] tag? It's not a "request for help with the site", is it. More like [meta-tag:feature-request] as a request to change things. I used [meta-tag:discussion] because it was not clear what to do. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request shows the prevalence of [meta-tag:discussion], too.

Comment: @ivan See the instructions in the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonym-request/info). [discussion] is fine/appropriate if you want a discussion, but this is past the discussion phase and into the [support] phase (get a mod to do it). [feature-request] is never appropriate for retag/synonym requests. They aren't features.